# How to multiply a constant array by a user input array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, math, dom

How do I apply my constant array by an array the user inputs and get the sum?

The user always enters 6 digits but constant is 5 digits

**Example**

[5, 7, 3, 5, 2] is my constant array that I am multiplying by

user enters 837465

turns into [8, 3,7,4,6,5]  (but I want 5 to be ignored)

multiply by constant array(not including last element) and get sum:

(8*5)+ (3*7) + (7*3) + (4*5)+ (6*2) = 114

```
const arr = [5, 7, 3, 5, 2];
var arr2 = [];
var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("yourNumber").value); //input from .html

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i< num.length; i++){  //var i = 1 b/c user always enters 6 digits, i feel this is wrong?
    arr2.push(parseInt(num[i]));
    sum += (arr2[i]*arr[i]);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: `i` should go from `0` to `arr.length`. Make sure to check if your number has enough digits before the loop (>=`arr.length`). Also, you don't need to convert the value to integer, since you will be using each digit (i.e, each _character_) separately. Then, the operation is just `sum+=arr[i]*num[i]`, you can access each character of a string as if it were an array.

Comment: thank you!!! it worked

Answer (score 1):

try use `const input = '837465'.split('')` or ready array `const input = [8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]` and reduce() method for summation array. 
reduce will work while there are elements in the original **array**

```js
const array = [5, 7, 3, 5, 2]
const input = '837465'.split('')
//or 
// const input = [8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]

const summ = (input) => array.reduce((acum, rec, index) => acum + (rec * input[index]), 0)

console.log(summ(input))
```

Comment: Beautiful answer !

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
const arr = [5, 7, 3, 5, 2];
var num = document.getElementById("yourNumber").value; //input from .html

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i< num.length-1; i++){  //var i = 1 b/c user always enters 6 
digits, i feel this is wrong?
    sum += (arr[i]*parseInt(num[i]));
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it imperatively using the legible `for`-`of` syntax -

```js
const arr = [5, 7, 3, 5, 2]
const nums = [8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]

let result = 0

for (const [ key, value ] of Object.entries(arr))
  result = result + (value * nums[key])

console.log(result) // 114
```

Or you can do it declaratively using `Array.prototype.reduce` -

```js
const arr = [5, 7, 3, 5, 2]
const nums = [8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]

const result =
  arr.reduce
    ( (sum, value, key) => sum + (value * nums[key])
    , 0
    )

console.log(result) // 114
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer (please click on Run code Snippet)

If you need any explanation, or this is not what you are asking about, please comment on my answer

```js
function getTotal() {
  const arr = [5, 7, 3, 5, 2];
  var userNumbers = document.getElementById('yourNumber').value.split(''); 
  var sum = 0;
  //itreate over your array case it is short (or a condition to itreate over the shortest one)
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(userNumbers[i]) * arr[i];
  }

  console.log(sum);
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML ='Answer will be here: '+ sum;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>StackOverFlow &#127831;</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/2057/2057586.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Stack Over Flow &#127831;</h3>

  <input id="yourNumber" type="text" value="837465">

  <button onclick="getTotal()">get the answer</button>
  
  <p id="answer">Answer will be here: </p>

</body>

</html>
```